# Remove/hide category bar from custom page

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have registered new controller in order to display new page. It works fine I was able to hide left column by calling:

```
public function init()
{
    $this->page_name = 'My products';
    $this->disableBlocks();
    parent::init();
}

protected function disableBlocks()
{
    $this->display_column_left = false;
}
```

in controller. Although I still have this bar present:
[image]

How can I hide it for my current controller (only for my custom one)? Of course prefered way is using some hooks or something, not just override template in theme. Is there maybe any other way to define layout for controller page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly from your backend. 
Go on modules -> position and look for the form: "blocktopmenu".
The hook is "displayTop", go to edit and select the page in which you do not want it to appear

Answer (score 0):

You should render a TPL file using your custom controller and write the following CSS code in it to hide the Top Menu bar:

```
#block_top_menu {
    display: none;
}
```

Note: You can also use some JS (or JQuery) to do it using the same procedure.